# Fatal error when injecting Apigility v1.4 into Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, laminas-api-tools, zend-framework3

I've juts included 4 new packages: `zfcampus/zf-apigility`, `zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin`, `zfcampus/zf-development-mode` and `rwoverdijk/assetmanager` (not sure why though but fair enough) into my ZF3 project in order to start to use Apigility.

After that the website now displays this stack trace:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Unable to resolve service &quot;InputFilterManager&quot; to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?' in D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php:670
Stack trace:
#0 D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(746): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager-&gt;getFactory('InputFilterMana...')
#1 D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(195): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager-&gt;doCreate('InputFilterMana...')
#2 D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zfcampus\zf-content-validation\src\ContentValidationListenerFactory.php(31): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager-&gt;get('InputFilterMana...')
#3 D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(747):  in <b>D:\RZECZY_ADAMA\_XAMPP\xampp-5.6\htdocs\zend3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php</b> on line <b>670</b><br />
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** It turns up, that I needed another pacakge: `Zend\InputFilter`, after importing it via Composer and adding it into modules.config.php it started to show my previous website. **I still can't see Administration Panel of Apigility after running: `php public/index.php development enable`**.

**EDIT: [23/11/2016]** I've had to add AssetManager to `development.config.php` & dist (yeah I know this could easily be copied with development-enable script). and it started to work. For anybody else who will struggle as me, here is a `development.config.php` modules list:

```
'modules' => [
    'ZF\Apigility\Admin',
    'ZF\Apigility\Admin\Ui',
    'ZF\Configuration',
    'AssetManager'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

That caused by module configuration cached. It was generated at first time to speed up reading configuration. So, after adding new modules always remove the cache in `data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php`
It will be created automatically if not found.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue I have the following: `'module_listener_options' => [
    'config_glob_paths' => [realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}-development.php'],
    'config_cache_enabled' => false,
    'module_map_cache_enabled' => false,
],` and I am in dev mode. I've even deleted the cache and it wasn't regenerated so it's not a cache issue.